# SignalR Hub ResolutionFailedException with Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, signalr

I am getting a really annoying ResolutionFailedException error when trying to resolve a SignalR hub using Unity in an MVC web application.  My code is displayed below.

My Bootstrapper Class

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        var unityDependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

        //Used for MVC
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(unityDependencyResolver);

        //Used for SignalR
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new SignalRUnityDependencyResolver(container);

        return container;
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>(); 

        RegisterTypes(container);

        return container;
    }

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

        //Repositories
        
        container.RegisterType<ChatMessageRepository>();
        

        //Services 
        container.RegisterType<CapturePoolService>();
        container.RegisterType<HistoricalDataService>();

        //Context
        container.RegisterType<ICustomPrincipal, CustomPrincipal>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IDatabaseFactory, DatabaseFactory>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

        //Hubs
        container.RegisterType<ChatHub>(new InjectionFactory(CreateChatHub));

    }

    private static object CreateChatHub(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new ChatHub(container.Resolve<ChatMessageRepository>(), container.Resolve<UnitOfWork>());
    }

}
```

My Chat Hub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ChatMessageRepository _chatMessageRepository;
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ChatHub(
        ChatMessageRepository chatMessageRepository,
        UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _chatMessageRepository = chatMessageRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

}

Now, I have a few different views which each use an instance of the Chat Hub (e.g. think of it as separate chat rooms which all utilized the same logic written in my hub).  When I go into one of these "rooms" my logic works as expected.  However, the problem arises when I leave that page and go to any other page in my application.  Here's the error:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Core.Repositories.ChatMessageRepository", name = "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>
> ---
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Repositories.ChatMessageRepository,(none)
>
> Resolving parameter "dbFactory" of constructor Repositories.ChatMessageRepository(Library.IDatabaseFactory dbFactory)
>
> Resolving Context.DatabaseFactory,(none) (mapped from Library.IDatabaseFactory, (none))

Which fires from my SignalRUnityDependencyResolver

```
public override Object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.Resolve(serviceType): base.GetService(serviceType);
    }
```

Specifically the "_container.Resolve(serviceType)" call.

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by registering my hub with the HierarchicalLifetimeManager.